# Database replication using OGG replication (initial load) to Kafka

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, database-replication, oracle-golden-gate

I have an issue with replication to Kafka over OGG Replicate (Loading Data from File to Replicate). Kafka topic size is not scalable because of HDD size restriction on server. I need to load 200 GB (from 1 table) of data over (initial load) replication, but I have only 100 GB free space on remote server. Is there any options to make restrictions for replication?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question.  If you have less space on target to hold the data, then your only choice is to filter the data on the source, only extract partil data and replicate them.  I am sure this could be achieved by adding sql predicate in initial load,  maybe check out the following support notes below

Oracle Support Document 971785.1 (How Do I Use "SQLPREDICATE" For An Initial Load Extract With A "WHERE" Clause?) can be found at: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=971785.1